# Concatenates instead of Addition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arithmetic-expressions

```
var tt = gas+0.1
document.write (vartt);
```

Duplicate

Comment: There are [*many duplicates*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%5Bjavascript%5D+concatenate+not+add).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user entered a string.  If you want to do arithmetic with it instead of string concatenation, you must convert to a number.  There are many different ways to do that including `parseInt(gas, 10)`, `parseFloat(gas)`, `Number(gas)` and `+gas`:

Here's one implementation:

```
var tt = parseFloat(gas) + 0.1; 
document.write(tt);
```

Also, your `document.write()` statement was not correct either.  The variable name is just `tt`, not `vartt`.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of Number function too.

```
var tt = Number(gas) + 0.1;
document.write(tt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using `<input type="number" />` for the input, the user provided data will be a string.  By default, when you try to add a string + a number it will cast that number to a string.  You can do what Видул Петров suggested and add the unary `+` to `gas` to force cast it to a number, however if it's still a string that can't be cast to a number (like someone entering in the word 'five' vs '5'), youll get `NaN` as a result unless you have the proper control over the incoming data.